# Join()ing on multiple threads and handling leaked output

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, interrupt, dining-philosopher

I'm solving a multi-threaded problem in Java and have the core problem itself resolved, but my output isn't what I'd expect.

I have a main thread that spins new threads that each perform their tasks. It looks like the following (pseudocode):

```
initializeThreads();            // Creates the new threads
startThreads();                 // Starts the new threads
sleep( duration );              // Lets the threads run for `duration` time
shutdownThreads();              // interrupt the threads
printOutput();                  // output the results to the console

// definition of shutdownThreads() is at the end of my question
```

My issue happens upon trying to `join()` on each thread in my list of threads. Every now and then my program gets caught in an endless loop because I'm guessing the `interrupt()` I call on my list of threads doesn't happen fast enough compared to the `join()` and not all the threads get interrupted.

My other issue occurs when the program *does* shutdown the threads correctly and print the termination output. While the program is running each thread has messages that it logs to the console, and after I interrupt the threads and display the final program message some of these thread-specific logging messages leak out to the console.

For example, let's say one of my threads outputs `"Thread-1 waiting for lock on object..."` while it runs, and the main program finally wakes itself up, terminates the thread, and outputs `"Program finished"`. Sometimes, the thread-specific message will show up *after* the program termination message.

If anyone could help me figure out how to stop this from happening please let me know!

**shutdownThreads()**

```
   private void shutdownThreads() {

    Thread t;
    for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
      t = threads.get(i);

      t.interrupt();
     }

    for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
      t = threads.get(i);
      try {
        t.join();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       System.out.println("Interrupted while waiting on thread to exit");
      }
    }
```

}

**EDIT:** One thing I thought of doing is rewriting `shutdownThreads()` to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
  Thread t = threads.get(i);

  t.interrupt();

  while (!t.isInterrupted()) ;
}
```

but this doesn't seem too elegant.

Comment: You should considering using an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).  Instead of creating Threads, you would simply submit Callables to the ExecutorService's [invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method.

Answer (score 0):

Your edited code at the bottom, that's gonna be a forever loop before it iterates the for() twice.

Comment: What do you mean? It will run for however large `threads` is. It gets the thread at `i`, interrupts it, then busy-waits until the thread is interrupted.

Comment: Why not sleep? It's cost effective on resources.